# awk conditions failed on input file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I ran `awk -F= '$20+0 >= 99  && $31+0 >= 50' sample.txt` but it did not find any hits with the below file:

```
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_016515887.1  XP_016515887.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC107832536 [Nicotiana tabacum]  2.7e-36 161.4   407 95  200 1   94  88  181 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLMWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEVIRQDMAKMRI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MNFHLQDGIEKGLVENDKKDHGEDERNDHEQDGRNDHVEVEPLAMTHETWKTELQVCLKGKFYKAVVRPAMLYGVECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLMWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEVIRQDMAKMRISEDMTLDRKVWRSSIRVVG    161.4   407 94  80.9    76  18  85  0   0   90.4    0   14HL20ED6TR1RM3NH11NS4EAIV2GARS1DG5KR4LV4RMTARK1QRVI    80.9    2.7e-36 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_016492639.1  XP_016492639.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC107812125 [Nicotiana tabacum]  2.3e-35 158.3   399 95  316 1   94  188 281 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAETRMLKWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLRWFEHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLTVVGARRGRGRPKRYWGEVITQDMARMRI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MTSISVNQFGFIPGRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEQFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLEKAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGVKTRVKTVSGDSNHFPVVMGLDQGSALSPLLSKTDHLECKFSAEPSEVGRDMKIGSQVIAKRRLALGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYEAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAETRMLKWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLRWFEHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLTVVGARRGRGRPKRYWGEVITQDMARMRIFEDMALDRKVWRYQGCRIGASRIFRTPFPGLGGAW    158.3   399 94  79.8    75  19  84  0   0   89.4    0   5MT3RK4HL20ED6TR4GENH11NS4ETIV2GA2DG5KR4LV1RT2RMTA2QRVI 79.8    2.3e-35 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_016503695.1  XP_016503695.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC107821758, partial [Nicotiana tabacum] 8.8e-35 156.4   394 95  205 1   94  93  186 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAETRMLRWMCGFTRLDKIRNEVIREKVGVASADEKLREARLRWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLEVVGASRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRHDMTSMWI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* SKTEYLECKFSAESSKEEVGRVVKLGSQAIAQRDIFKYLGLGQGGRNGGLHQESCVTRKCQKLKGKYYRAVVRPSMLYGAECWPVKKSHVQRMKVAETRMLRWMCGFTRLDKIRNEVIREKVGVASADEKLREARLRWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLEVVGASRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRHDMTSMWISEDMALDRRVWRSNIRVVG   156.4   394 94  78.7    74  20  82  0   0   87.2    0   5MT8HF6KR11PSVAED2ML3TR5NH11NS5IV2GARS1DG10LV2QH1RM1RS1QWVI 78.7    8.8e-35 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 OIT34550.1  OIT34550.1 putative ubiquitin-like-specific protease 2b [Nicotiana attenuata]   1.1e-34 156.0   393 95  574 1   94  175 268 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRIDKIRNGDIREKVGVAPMEDKMREARLRWFGHIQRRSTDAPVRRCERLAVVGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIGQDMTRLRI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MCHIPYFSPFLFALVMDAITHHIQGEVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETQRGVNERLEVWRHALESKDFRLSRTKTEHLECKFGAEPTEAGVEVRLDSQVIPKRGSFKYLGSVIQGIGEIDEDVTHRIGVGWMKWRLATGVLCDKKVPPSLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGTECWPVKNSHIQKMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRIDKIRNGDIREKVGVAPMEDKMREARLRWFGHIQRRSTDAPVRRCERLAVVGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIGQDMTRLRITEDMALDRELWRSSIKVVGFGKKGTDEELPSQSRSTEHPRTCQKRKSKKVAAALDSAVLLRRSARLRGLSNKRNGKSDGKLNSVDFDCYLENIWRELPEDKKSSFTYLESMWFYLYTTKLFKAKVLRWIKGLDIFSKKYVFVPIVLWDHWCLLIFCNLGGSLESESKTPCMLLLDSLHMAGPSPYESEIRKFVLDIFKNEERPESQQLIKKIKLLIPKVPQQTNGTDCGKFALYFISLFLESAPENFSISEGYPYFMKRDWFTPDQLESFWLELPTLTKDSSEDMKNTAVSGESVSGSEDAIIYLV  156.0   393 94  76.6    72  22  84  0   0   89.4    0   17LI3KR1EGVD9VM1ED5TR5NHVIRQ3PT5NR4EAIV2GT2DG10LV1RG2RM2MLQRVI  76.6    1.1e-34 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_016512735.1  XP_016512735.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC107829780 [Nicotiana tabacum]  2.0e-34 155.2   391 95  259 1   94  133 226 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEIRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLRWFGHMRRRSPDAPVRICEWLAVVGVRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRHDMDSMRI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MRVGVNERLEVWRQTLDSKGFRIRRPKTEYLECKFSAEASEVGRKVKIGSQVIAKKDCFKYLGSLIQGDGEIDGDVTHLIGAGWSKLSLVSRVLCDKKVPQKLKGEFYRAVVRPTMLYGAECWPVKKSHVQRMKVAEIRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLRWFGHMRRRSPDAPVRICEWLAVVGVRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRHDMDSMRISEDMALDRITWRSSIRVVGQRHLEFLALLYRDG 155.2   391 94  79.8    75  19  83  0   0   88.3    0   5MI8HL20ED6TR5NHVM10NI2RW1EAIV2GV2DG10LV2QH1RMTDRS1QRVI 79.8    2.0e-34 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_009783549.1  XP_009783549.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC104232135 [Nicotiana sylvestris]   3.3e-34 154.5   389 95  232 2   94  121 213 KVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV   KVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIRNEDIRERVSVAPVDDKMREARFRWFGHVRRRSLDAPVRRCERLTLAGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRQDMARLQI   MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MRRDAALIGDWRTKTEYVECKFSDVTGEADVEVRLDSQVILKRESFKYLGSIIQGDGEINRDVTHRIGVEWMKWRLAFGVLCDKNVSQKLKGKFYKVVVRPTMLYGVECWPVKNSHIQKIKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIRNEDIRERVSVAPVDDKMREARFRWFGHVRRRSLDAPVRRCERLTLAGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRQDMARLQISEDMALDRNMWRSNIRVVG    154.5   389 93  77.4    72  21  81  0   0   87.1    0   20KR2VD3KR1GS4EDED5TRLF4NH5PL5NR4ETILVA1GT2DG10LV4RMTA1ML1VI    77.4    3.3e-34 97.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_018627647.1  XP_018627647.1 uncharacterized protein LOC104100193 [Nicotiana tomentosiformis] 9.7e-34 152.9   385 95  161 1   94  49  142 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRMDKIRNEDIREKVGVAPMEDKMREVRLRWFGHIQRRSTDAPVRRCERLAVVGTRRGRGRPKKYWEEVIRDDMARLRI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MKWRLASGVLCDKKVPPLLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGTECWPVKNSHIQKMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRMDKIRNEDIREKVGVAPMEDKMREVRLRWFGHIQRRSTDAPVRRCERLAVVGTRRGRGRPKKYWEEVIRDDMARLRITEDMALDRELWRSSIKVVG   152.9   385 94  74.5    70  24  82  0   0   87.2    0   17LM3KR2VD9VM1ED4AVTR5NHVIRQ3PT5NR4EAIV2GT2DG8GE1LV2QD1RMTA1MLQRVI  74.5    9.7e-34 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_016478590.1  XP_016478590.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC107799961 [Nicotiana tabacum]  1.3e-33 152.5   384 95  228 1   94  116 209 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCRLTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVEMAPVDEKMREARLRWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGMRRGRGRPKRCWGEVIRHDMARMRV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MVGVNEMLDVWRQTLESKGFKISRAKTEYLKCKFSAEPSEVGRDVKIGSQRDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAILYRAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCRLTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVEMAPVDEKMREARLRWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGMRRGRGRPKRCWGEVIRHDMARMRVSEDMTLDRKVWRSSIRVVG    152.5   384 94  78.7    74  20  83  0   0   88.3    0   13GRHL12EQ2GEVM3ED6TR5NH11NS4EAIV2GM2DG5KRYC3LV2QH1RMTA2QR1 78.7    1.3e-33 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_019244552.1  XP_019244552.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC109224430 [Nicotiana attenuata]    1.7e-33 152.1   383 95  208 1   94  49  142 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKAAEMSMLRWMCGHTRMDKVRNEGIREKVGVAPIDDNMREARLRWFGHVQRRSLDAPVRRCERLALVGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRRDMARLQI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MKWRLASGVLCDKKVPLLLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHTKKMKAAEMSMLRWMCGHTRMDKVRNEGIREKVGVAPIDDNMREARLRWFGHVQRRSLDAPVRRCERLALVGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRRDMARLQISEDMALDRKLWRSSIKVVGGIVEMIVRVFARDLSVLLLLLIFGDKASFIYRGLRISETRQDNYLCR    152.1   383 94  73.4    69  25  82  0   0   87.2    0   2VA3RS10LM2IVKR2VG9VIEDEDKN4TR5NH1RQ3PL5NR4EAIL2GT2DG10LV2QR1RMTA1ML1VI 73.4    1.7e-33 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 OIT28878.1  OIT28878.1 dead-box atp-dependent rna helicase 32 [Nicotiana attenuata] 8.2e-33 149.8   377 95  1094    1   85  392 476 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELI   MKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIRNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRKSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEVL   MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MRKHTPKSRKAKIQSRLSEVHEIELLEAWIESGKPESGSNPLSLEPLPHKAPIGRLPDGSFSRYAGCDRFSQLPVSKKTKDGLIDCKFKTMTDIQRASLPHSLCGRDILGAAKTGSGKTLAFVIPFGFMPDRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEHFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLEKAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFPVVMGLHQGFALSPLLFALVMDAITCHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGGNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRAKTEYLECKFSAEPSEVGRDVKLGSKVIAKRDNFRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHHIGEGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKSYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIRNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRKSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEVLEKLYKARWGEEDGVGCIIMSPTRELAGQLFDVLKSVGKHHGFSAGLLIGGRKDVDTEKEHVNSLNILVCTPGRLLQHMDETPNFDCSQLQVLVLDEADRILDVGFKRELNAIISQLPKHRQTLLFSATQTKSVQDLARLSLKDPEYLGVHEESDTATPNRLQQTAMLVPLDKKLDMLWSFIKAHLNSRILVFLSSCKQVKFVFEAFKKLRPGIPLKCLHGRMKQDRRMGIYSQFCEQRSVLFSTDVASRGLDFNKAVDWVVQVDCPEDCAAYIHRVGRTARYLSGGRSLLFVMPSEMKMLEKLEEKKIPLRVIKANEKRIQSVSDLLASLLVKYPDLQHLSQRAFVTYLKSIHKQRDKEIFDVTKLPIDEFSASLGLPMTPKIRFLKQKLKGKTVSEALSLLPDDTSNDNLLELPIRKPDTGKSEGEEVEEDLLLAKETQEVGELKINSKGDDMLATRVLKKKKLKINVHRPVGTRVVFDEEGNTLPPLARLADTSSGADSVQLNKEKVNQRYAELRKNLKLADKEDKDLDRKRLQEKRIKEKMKYKRGREEEEDEELSESDGELPGGRVNKKTKIFDSDDDDGDKSKDMAKEGIAADAISVAEQEELALKLLSSMNS  149.8   377 85  81.2    69  16  79  0   0   92.9    0   14HL6KR13ED6TR3FY1NH3RK7NS4EAIV2GARS1DG5KR4LVIL 81.2    8.2e-33 89.5
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_018634600.1  XP_018634600.1 uncharacterized protein LOC108949236 [Nicotiana tomentosiformis] 8.2e-33 149.8   377 95  202 1   94  90  183 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIRNVEFREKVGMAPMDDKMREARLRWFGHVRRRSIDAPVRGCETLALAGTRGGRGRPKKYWGEVIRQDMARLQI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MDVRLDSQAIPKRGNFKYLESIIQGDGEIDEDVTHRIGVGRMKWGLASGVLFDKKVPPKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWAAKNSHTQKMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIRNVEFREKVGMAPMDDKMREARLRWFGHVRRRSIDAPVRGCETLALAGTRGGRGRPKKYWGEVIRQDMARLQISEDMALDREGWRSRIRVVG  149.8   377 94  74.5    70  24  80  0   0   85.1    0   21KR1EVVEIF5VM2VMEDED5TR5NH5PI5NG2RT1EAILVA1GT1RGDG10LV4RMTA1ML1VI  74.5    8.2e-33 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_019238436.1  XP_019238436.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC109218522 [Nicotiana attenuata]    3.1e-32 147.9   372 95  161 1   94  49  142 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAKMRMLRWMCGHTRIDKIRNEVIRDKVGVAPVDDKMRELRLRWFGHVQRRSTDAPVRRCERLAVAGLRRGRGRLKKYWGEMITQDMALLQL  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MNWGLASGVLCDKKVPPRLKGKFYRVVVRPTMLYVAECWPIKNFHFQRMKVAKMRMLRWMCGHTRIDKIRNEVIRDKVGVAPVDDKMRELRLRWFGHVQRRSTDAPVRRCERLAVAGLRRGRGRLKKYWGEMITQDMALLQLTEDMIQDRRAWKSKIRVVG   147.9   372 94  73.4    69  25  81  0   0   86.2    0   4EK12LI3KR5ED7EDED4ALTR5NH1RQ3PT5NR4EAIVVA1GL2DG3PL6LM1RT2RMTARLML1VL   73.4    3.1e-32 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_016515386.1;XP_033517730.1   XP_016515386.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC107832086 [Nicotiana tabacum]  2.0e-31 145.2   365 95  599 1   94  70  163 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVVEMRMLRWMCGHTRRDKIRNEVIRDKVGVAPLEAKMRELRLRWFGHVQRKSTDAPVSRCERLAVAGLRRGRGRPKKYWAEVIRQDMALLQL  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MMSKGFKLSRAKTEYLECKFSDGTHEADVKVKLDTQVIPRRSSFKYLGSIIRGNGEIDDEVSHRIGAGRMKVVEMRMLRWMCGHTRRDKIRNEVIRDKVGVAPLEAKMRELRLRWFGHVQRKSTDAPVSRCERLAVAGLRRGRGRPKKYWAEVIRQDMALLQLTEDMIQDRRVWSSKIKVKAWVAEKDAEALRCQKLLFEEEEAAQKKQAELLERKKVKKLRQKEQKAKEQSIEEKGILEAPANIPDVSVGISTCLEMVQFSSNVDTSVESQYDLCHQHLDSVKVQNLEPRPVSANSRRRFANSQLQAPKSQRFGRNGGFHNNQNHQALKAEPIQKHKDSGTPVNSCMIWTRKVRVESDDTSILEVQKEDIDQKQRNSEVIIGSISVPVKDCSTQQQGRDDFGSTELRKKCNAVEKPAKHDALQIGSNRAAAKLWRPVRHTVGRQDPEEEGVMSSKFDDGTSLNENSLQSCPVDSSGSRKNCQVPDGNAHQGLGYSSIAAKAFLAQRWREAIAGDHVRLVLSPDTESSERPEVPSSSSEAAPASDSGEHGVVSRADTELTKNEVLTSSSSGSIKVKYRPKPEKGVKTMYIPKQKNHHLG 145.2   365 94  72.3    68  26  78  0   0   83.0    0   3AV13LR3KR5ED6VL1EA4ALTR5NH1RQ1RK1PT4RSNR4EAIVVA1GL2DG8GA1LV4RMTARLML1VL    72.3    2.0e-31 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_033510858.1  XP_033510858.1 uncharacterized protein LOC117275662 [Nicotiana tomentosiformis] 2.6e-31 144.8   364 95  258 1   94  160 253 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MNVTEMRILRWMCGHIRLDKVRNEDIREKVGVASMEDKMHEARLRWFGHVRRRSLDAPVRRCEQLALAGRRRGRGRPKKYWGDVIRQDMARLQL  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MDTPTRHIQGEVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRGGVNEKLEVCRQTLESKGFELSKTKTEYLECKFNVVTWGANIAVRLDSQVIPNRGSFKYLRSVIQGSGEIGEDVTHRIGAGWAKWRLASGVLCDKNVPPKLKGQFYKAAIRLGMLYGAECWPVKNSHIQKMNVTEMRILRWMCGHIRLDKVRNEDIREKVGVASMEDKMHEARLRWFGHVRRRSLDAPVRRCEQLALAGRRRGRGRPKKYWGDVIRQDMARLQLTWPLT  144.8   364 94  71.3    67  27  79  0   0   84.0    0   1KN1AT3MI7TI4IVKR2VD8PSVM1ED2RH2TR5NH5PL5NR2RQ1EAILVA1GR2DG9EDLV4RMTA1ML1VL 71.3    2.6e-31 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 OIT40319.1  OIT40319.1 exocyst complex component sec6 [Nicotiana attenuata] 2.6e-31 144.8   364 95  1287    1   83  993 1075    MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGE MKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIRNEVIREKVGVALVEEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCEQLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGE MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MMAEDLGVEAKEASVREVAKLLPLPELLQSISSIKADYIARQQANDAQLSTMVAEQVEQAQAGLQSLNSSQKTINQLRENFLSIEKLCQECQNLIENHDQIKLLSNTRNNLNTTLKDVEGMMSISVEASEARDSLRDDKELINTYERLTALDGKRRFALAAAGSHKEEVGRLREYFEDVDQTWETFEKTLWAHIANFSKLAKESPQTLVRAIRVVEMQEILDQQLAEEAAEAEGGGAMASIANPRRNAKKTPSSKNLTQQKLKVQGKGYKDKCYESIRKSVEARFDKLLNEEELKTAIEEARVMGEELGEIYDYVAPCFPPRYEVFQLMVNLYTERFVQWLRKLSDQANNMTNIEILKVTGWVVDYQESLIGLGVDDSLAQVCSESGAMDPLMNAYVERMQATTKKWYLNILEADKVQPPKKTDDGKLYTPAAVDLFRILGEQVQIVRENSTDVMLYRIALALIQVMIDFQAAERKRLEEPASEIGLESLCAMINNNLRCYDLAMELSSSTLEALPQNYAEQVNFEDTCKGFLEVAKYGEADAMWSETANLVREAARDVLGVAKGYSGRHQGDWWWNDVVQGKVEAKKAAFAKLAGSSSEEERRANRESYKVARKEAKLAVTEAKNAAFGRMYEELGEKGGDRKLFRLAKVRERKARDLDQVRCIKDEDGRVLMGESQVKQRWQAYFRDLLNEEGDRDVELGELGNSEFHRDLGYCRRIRVEEVVGALRRMSRGRATGPDEIPVEFWKCIGRSGVEWLSRLFNVIFRTKRMPEEWRDKKKDLHMVFIDLEKAFDKVPREVLWRCREAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFSVVMGLHQGSALSPLLFALVMDAITRHIQRDVPWCMLFADDIVLLDETRVGVNERLEVWRKTLESKGFKLSRAKTEYLECKFSAEPSEGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWWKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRVVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIRNEVIREKVGVALVEEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCEQLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEEAVHQTVSVIFEDPGVEELLVKLYQKDWLEGQVTEFLVATFSDYFTDVKMYIEERSFRRFVEACLEETVVVYVDHLLTQKNYIKEETIERMRLDEEVLMDFFREYISVSKVENRVRILSDLRELASSESPDSFTLVYTNILEQQPDCPPEVVEKIVGLREGIPRKDAKEVVQECKEIYEHSLVDGNPPKTGFVFPRVKCLSAAKHSIWRKLT 144.8   364 83  83.1    69  14  76  0   0   91.6    0   14HL6KR11PL8TR3FY1NH11NS2RQ1EAIV2GARS1DG5KR4    83.1    2.6e-31 87.4
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_009775799.1  XP_009775799.1 PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC104225652 [Nicotiana sylvestris]   3.5e-31 144.4   363 95  265 2   94  146 238 KVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV   KVAEIRMLKWMCEHTRLDKIRNEDIRERVCVAPVDDKMREAQLRWFVHVRKRSLDAPVRRCERLTLAGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRQDMARLQI   MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MLFADDIVLIDETRGGVNGRLEVWRQALESKGFKLSRTKTEYVECKFSDVTEEVDVEVRLGSQVILKRESFKYLRLIIHGDGEIDGDVTHRIGVGWMKWILASGVLCDKNVPPKLKSKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAEFWPVKNPHIQKIKVAEIRMLKWMCEHTRLDKIRNEDIRERVCVAPVDDKMREAQLRWFVHVRKRSLDAPVRRCERLTLAGTRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRQDMARLQISEDMALDSYLLLYASNGAVSNGGIEEV   144.4   363 93  73.1    68  25  80  0   0   86.0    0   4MI3RK3GE7KR2VD3KR1GC4EDED5TQ4GVNH2RK2PL5NR4ETILVA1GT2DG10LV4RMTA1ML1VI 73.1    3.5e-31 97.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 OIT33527.1  OIT33527.1 hypothetical protein A4A49_14946 [Nicotiana attenuata]   5.9e-31 143.7   361 95  885 1   94  116 209 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MRVAEMRMLRWMCGNTRMDKIRNVDIREKVLVAPIDDKMREARLRWFGHVQRRSPDAPVRMCEQLVMEGTRRGRRRPKKYWEEVIRQDMTRLQI  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MSLDKSTTTKTEYMECKFTAEPGQVGVDMRLESQVIPSRGNFKYLGSVIHGGGEIDEDVTHRIGVGWMKWRLASGVLCDKRLLPLLKGKFYKAVVRPAMMYGAECWPVKNLHIQKMRVAEMRMLRWMCGNTRMDKIRNVDIREKVLVAPIDDKMREARLRWFGHVQRRSPDAPVRMCEQLVMEGTRRGRRRPKKYWEEVIRQDMTRLQIFEDMTLDRKMWRSSIRVIGLAHHDNYHEFCRLLGRFKVNYQLSELVNVESYGDWIRLVAEFTLRSLQSWQWASSSVYYLLGLWSRLVSSVPYLKGDTPSLLSEFVPEIVKSFITSRFGSFQGEISDLSENPLDNVDLLQDQLDCLPYLCRFQYESCSSYIMQITDPLLQMYMESADPQVLTVVETKFAWIVHIIAAIVKTKQLSGYSGESQEILDAELSARVLRLINVTDSGLRSQRYAETSKQRLDLAILVFFQNFRKSYVGDQAIHSSKQLYAKLAELLGLHDHMLILNVIVGKIATNLKFYGESEEVISQTLNLMLEMASGYMTAKLLVKLDTTQLIISNRNREEFPFLGDFRCSRSRTTFYYIIGLLIFMEDSFLKFKASMDPLLQVLLSLELILDALFRTDDVKQALIGLMRDLRGIAMATSSRRTYGFLFDWLYPAHIPLLLKAIRIWADTPEVTTPLLKFIAEFVLNKSQRLNFEISSPNGILLFREVSKLIVAYGSRILSLPSHVDMYQFKYKGIWISLTILSRALAGNYVNFGVFEIYGDRALADAFDISMRMALSIPLADILAYRKLSGAYFTFLEIMMKNQIHLILNLDSSSFIFIAGSLESGLKVLDANIKSQCASAVDNLATFYFDHITAGESPTNPEALNLAQHLADCPNIFLEVSSTALFI   143.7   361 94  72.3    68  26  82  0   0   87.2    0   1KR12HN2LM3KR1EVVD5GL3VIEDED5TR5NH1RQ9NM2RQ1EVIMVE1GT2DG1GR6GE1LV4RM2ML1VI  72.3    5.9e-31 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_033512047.1  XP_033512047.1 uncharacterized protein LOC104096328 [Nicotiana tomentosiformis] 5.9e-31 143.7   361 95  413 1   94  226 319 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMSMLRWMCGHTRLDRIMSEVIRDKVGVAPVEANMREARLRWFGHVKRRSTDAPVRRCERLALGGERRGRGRPKKSWGEVIRRDMEQLEL  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MNSDIFQFLCFNLEKAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKGVPVVYIRVIQDMYDGAKTQVRTAGGDSDYFPVEMGLHQGSALSPFLFSLAMDSLTLRIDETRGGVNERLEVWRHTLESKGFKLNKTKTEYFECKFSGVTQEADGDVRLDTQVIPRRESFKYLGSIIQKNEKIDEDVTHRIRAGWMKWRLASGVLCDKNVSLRLKGKFYKVVVRPTMLYGAECWPVKKSHVQQMKVAEMSMLRWMCGHTRLDRIMSEVIRDKVGVAPVEANMREARLRWFGHVKRRSTDAPVRRCERLALGGERRGRGRPKKSWGEVIRRDMEQLELTEDMTLDRRVWKLKIRVKGLPSPSLAEGLSETVSLPLQGRGKAALAVCFLLLGCSTDVYNLNELIVNSYQLPSKNDNNLSSSTSHESSISNFSI   143.7   361 94  72.3    68  26  80  0   0   85.1    0   6RS12KR1KMNS4ED8EAKN4TR5NH1RK3PT5NR4EAILVG1GE2DG6YS3LV2QR1RMTERQMLQEVL  72.3    5.9e-31 98.9
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 XP_033511396.1  XP_033511396.1 uncharacterized protein LOC117276177 [Nicotiana tomentosiformis] 7.7e-31 143.3   360 95  109 1   88  18  105 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQD    MKVAEMRMLRWICGHTRRDKIKNEVIRDKAGVAPVEEKMRELRLRWFGYVQRRSTDAPVKRCERLAVAGLRRGRGRANKFWGEVIRQD    MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MLYGAEYWPVKNSHVRGMKVAEMRMLRWICGHTRRDKIKNEVIRDKAGVAPVEEKMRELRLRWFGYVQRRSTDAPVKRCERLAVAGLRRGRGRANKFWGEVIRQDMALL   143.3   360 88  77.3    68  20  75  0   0   85.2    0   11MI5LR9ED1VA11ALTR5NY1RQ3PT4RKNR4EAIVVA1GL2DG3PAKN1YF3LV4  77.3    7.7e-31 92.6
chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1 KAF3643615.1    KAF3643615.1 putative pre-mRNA-processing factor 6-like [Capsicum annuum]   1.0e-30 142.9   359 95  209 1   94  97  190 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRGDRVRNETIREKVGVTPVECKMREARLRWFGHVKRRAMDAPVRRCERLALDGFRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRRDMEQLQL  MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV* MWKKVKVECNKGCLVLIGGDSNVRKSTLLLQINGEIDEDVSHRIGTGWMKWKLASGVLCDKKVPPKLKGKFYRVVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHIQKMKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRGDRVRNETIREKVGVTPVECKMREARLRWFGHVKRRAMDAPVRRCERLALDGFRRGRGRPKKYWGEVIRRDMEQLQLTEDMTLDRKVWRTRIRAED   142.9   359 94  72.3    68  26  80  0   0   85.1    0   14HL2LG1KRIVKR2VT7AT3EC5TR5NH1RK2SAPM5NR4EAILVD1GF2DG10LV2QR1RMTERQML1VL    72.3    1.0e-30 98.9
```

What did I miss?

Comment: The data in your file does not appear to be delimited by `=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @steeldriver already commented, the fields in your data seem not to be separated by `=`, so setting the `FS` (field separator) to this value using this assignment `-F=` would result to random output.

Furthermore, I don not see that fields `20` and `31` are what you want, even if you use the default field separator (the whitespaces).

---

### How to view your data, debug, decide and form your command

To identify the fields you want inside this file with long lines is a job for a program. Use awk first to see what these lines have. First have a better view and understanding of this file, and then decide what is the command you want to execute. Counting fields manually (by eye) is difficult for these long lines.

For example, examine only the first line. Running

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i, $i}' file
```

will give you the field index and value for all the content:

```
1 chr15_pilon_pilon.g1.t1
2 XP_016515887.1
3 XP_016515887.1
4 PREDICTED:
5 uncharacterized
6 protein
7 LOC107832536
8 [Nicotiana
9 tabacum]
10 2.7e-36
11 161.4
12 407
13 95
14 200
15 1
16 94
17 88
18 181
19 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV
20 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLMWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEVIRQDMAKMRI
21 MKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVEEKMREATLRWFGNVRRRSPDAPVRNCERLEIVGGRRDRGRPKKYWGELIRQDRTRMQV*
22 MNFHLQDGIEKGLVENDKKDHGEDERNDHEQDGRNDHVEVEPLAMTHETWKTELQVCLKGKFYKAVVRPAMLYGVECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGLTRLDKIKNEVIREKVGVAPVDEKMREARLMWFGHVRRRSPDAPVRSCERLAVVGASRGRGRPKRYWGEVIRQDMAKMRISEDMTLDRKVWRSSIRVVG
23 161.4
24 407
25 94
26 80.9
27 76
28 18
29 85
30 0
31 0
32 90.4
33 0
34 14HL20ED6TR1RM3NH11NS4EAIV2GARS1DG5KR4LV4RMTARK1QRVI
35 80.9
36 2.7e-36
37 98.9
```

Or the same, to get fields index and value only for numerical values:

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==$i+0) print i, $i}' file
```

```
10 2.7e-36
11 161.4
12 407
13 95
14 200
15 1
16 94
17 88
18 181
23 161.4
24 407
25 94
26 80.9
27 76
28 18
29 85
30 0
31 0
32 90.4
33 0
35 80.9
36 2.7e-36
37 98.9
```

Note that testing for `$i+0 == $i` is a standard awk idiom to test if a field is a numerical value.

Now you see your data. You can print some fields for more lines if you need. You can decide and form your command according to you needs.

Comment: +1 for explaining the "+0" syntax for other people who might read this question.